# Ao selecionar option exibe div com

Tags: jquery, html, formulário, html-select, jquery-select2

Eu tenho uma dúvida, como eu não manjo nada de `PHP`, eu gostaria que alguém me ajudasse como montar ou a implementar um `Jquery` que eu encontrei.

No meu caso são 2 *selects*, um que seria apelidado de `Estado` e outro `Cidade`, e quando seleciona o *Option* no `Estado`, exibe os outros *options* (no caso as `Cidades`) no *select* `Cidade`.

Até aí eu tenho ele pronto, vou deixar o código para quem precisar.
O que eu precisaria era de quando selecionar a segunda cidade, exibir uma *Div* com informações nela.

Por exemplo:

1. *select*: São Paulo
2. *select*: São Bernardo

> div: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis varius nisi vitae neque malesuada vehicula at eget ante. Morbi a eros consectetur, lobortis justo ut, elementum sapien. Praesent et mollis ante. Vestibulum dignissim eros sed est imperdiet, at aliquam nunc egestas. Vestibulum ut diam eu erat condimentum lacinia pulvinar at turpis. Pellentesque ac odio ut ante interdum molestie.

```js
var listadeCidades = new Array(4)
listadeCidades["Vazio"] = ["Cidade"];
listadeCidades["São Paulo"] = ["1a", "2a", "3a"];
listadeCidades["Rio de Janeiro"] = ["1b", "2b", "3b", "4b"];
listadeCidades["Paraná"] = ["1c", "2c", "3c"];
listadeCidades["Bahia"]= ["1d", "2d", "3d", "4d"];

function trocadeEstado(selectObj) {
 var idx = selectObj.selectedIndex;
 var which = selectObj.options[idx].value;
 cList = listadeCidades[which];
 var cSelect = document.getElementById("cidade_campo");
 var len=cSelect.options.length;
 while (cSelect.options.length > 0) {
  cSelect.remove(0);
 }
 var newOption;

 for (var i=0; i<cList.length; i++) {
  newOption = document.createElement("option");
  newOption.value = cList[i];
  newOption.text=cList[i];
  try {
   cSelect.add(newOption);
  }
  catch (e) {
   cSelect.appendChild(newOption);

  }
 }
}
```

```html
 <form action="" method="post"> 
    <span><label for="estado"><strong>*</strong>Estado:</label>
    <select name="estado_campo" id="estado_campo" onchange="trocadeEstado(this);" required>
        <option value="Vazio">Estado</option>
        <option value="São Paulo">São Paulo</option>
        <option value="Rio de Janeiro">Rio de Janeiro</option>
        <option value="Paraná">Paraná</option>
        <option value="Bahia">Bahia</option>
    </select>
    </span>
            
    <span>
    <label for="cidade_campo"><strong>*</strong>Cidade:</label>
    <select name="cidade_campo" id="cidade_campo" required>
     <option value="0">Cidade</option>
    </select>
 </span>
            
</form>
```

Comment: Vi que seu código está todo em *javascript* puro, você quer um exemplo de como fazer isso com javascript ou com jQuery?

Comment: Acho que faltou algo na frase *"Ao selecionar option exibe div com"*. "Com" o que?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Gustavo Teixeira**, valores em select boxes podem (devem) possuir valores exatos como números ou letras **SEM espaço e SEM acento**, de maneira a poder trabalhar com estes valores futuramente. Partindo deste princípio, seu select de estados passaria a ser:

```
<select name="estado_campo" id="estado_campo" required>
    <option value="">Estado</option>
    <option value="SP">São Paulo</option>
    <option value="RJ">Rio de Janeiro</option>
    <option value="PR">Paraná</option>
    <option value="BA">Bahia</option>
</select>
```

O próximo passo seria adicionar o div que conterá a informação da cidade escolhida:

```
<div id="idCidadeInfo">Selecione um estado e uma cidade</div>
```

Por último, o JQUERY constitui de:

1. Delcarar os objetos jQuery (select Cidade, select Estado e div Informações da cidade)
2. Declarar os objetos Estado e as Cidades (podem vir de fonte externa como banco de dados, JSON, etc, basta adaptá-los)
3. Trabalhar com o JQuery a fim de pesquisar nestes objetos conforme a seleção do usuário.

**Conclusão:**

Veja funcionando em: http://jsfiddle.net/felipe_douradinho/4vfnk1pj/3/

```
// Declara para reuso
var select_Estado = $('#estado_campo');
var select_Cidade = $('#cidade_campo');
var div_CidadeInfo = $('#idCidadeInfo');

var estados = { };

estados.SP = [
    {cidade: 'São Paulo', descricao: 'Grande cidade'},
    {cidade: 'Campinas', descricao: 'Descrição de Campinas'}
];

estados.RJ = [
    {cidade: 'Cabo Frio', descricao: 'Descrição de Cabo Frio'},
    {cidade: 'Niterói', descricao: 'Descrição de Niterói'}
];

estados.PR = [
    {cidade: 'Londrina', descricao: 'Descrição de Londrina'},
    {cidade: 'Luiziania', descricao: 'Descrição de Luiziania'}
];

estados.BA = [
    {cidade: 'Campinas', descricao: 'Descrição de Campinas'},
    {cidade: 'Biritinga', descricao: 'Descrição de Biritinga'}
];

// Quando escolher um estado
select_Estado.on('change', function()
{
    var estado = $(this).val();

    if(estado != "")
    {
        select_Cidade.html('<option value="">Cidade</option>');

        // preenche lista de cidades
        $.each(estados[estado], function(index, valor)
        {
            var o = new Option(valor.cidade, index);
            $(o).html(valor.cidade);
            select_Cidade.append(o);
        });
        div_CidadeInfo.html("Selecione uma cidade"); 
    }
    else
    {
           // Reseta select da cidade
           var o = new Option("Cidade", "")
           $(o).html("Cidade");
           select_Cidade.html(o);

           div_CidadeInfo.html("Selecione um estado e uma cidade");         
    }
});

// Quando escolher uma cidade
$('#cidade_campo').on('change', function()
{
    // Procura pela cidade no objeto 'estados' da linha #1 buscando pelo index da cidade
    var indexCidadeEscolhida = $(this).val(); // guarda o index da cidade

    if(indexCidadeEscolhida != "")
    {
        var cidadeEscolhida      = estados[select_Estado.val()][indexCidadeEscolhida];
        div_CidadeInfo.html(cidadeEscolhida.cidade + ' => ' + cidadeEscolhida.descricao);
    }
    else
    {
        div_CidadeInfo.html("Selecione uma cidade");         
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Partindo do pressuposto que você já consiga criar o segundo `<select>` com os seus respectivos valores, você pode usar a seguinte técnica:

1. Crie os conteúdos que você quer mostrar, e deixe-os escondidos por default, e com ids fazendo referência aos `<option>` do `<select>`.

   Isso significa, se você tem o HTML:

   ```
   <select name="cidade_campo" id="cidade_campo" required="">
       <option value="cidade1">1a</option>
       <option value="cidade2">2a</option>
       <option value="cidade3">3a</option>
   </select>
   ```

   Os conteúdos seriam:

   ```
   <div class="cidade-info" id="cidade1">Info cidade 1a</div>
   <div class="cidade-info" id="cidade2">Info cidade 2a</div>
   <div class="cidade-info" id="cidade3">Info cidade 3a</div>
   ```

   E o CSS:

   ```
   .cidade-info{
       display: none;
   }
   ```

   Dessa maneira, apesar de existirem já no seu DOM, os conteúdos referentes à cada uma das cidades estará escondido.

   Note que, no seu HTML, o atributo `value` dos `<option>` e o `id` das `<div>` de cada conteúdo são iguais. Esta referência é fundamental para que esta técnica funcione.
2. Crie uma classe para forçar o aparecimento do conteúdo, quando atribuída à ele:

   Isso pode ser feito no CSS:

   ```
   .active{
       display: block !important;
   }
   ```

   Você irá usar essa classe atribuindo-a para o conteúdo desejado, via jQuery (que foi o que você perguntou). O `!important` serve para garantir que o display da classe `active` vai ter prioridade sobre o da classe `cidade-info`. Com isso concluído,
3. Faça a atribuição da classe `active` usando jQuery, de acordo com a sua escolha.

   Para isso, basta fazer o bind de uma função, toda vez que você muda o valor do `<select>`. Basicamente:

   ```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
       $('#cidade_campo').on('change', function() {
           //Pego o valor do option
           var _val = $(this).val();  

           //Monto o seletor do conteúdo  
           var _seletor = '#' + _val; 

           //Adiciono a classe ao seletor escolhido
           $(_seletor).addClass('active'); 

           //Removo a classe dos irmãos dele, caso existam (e assim, escondo eles)
           $(_seletor).siblings().removeClass('active'); 
       });
   });
   ```

   Agora, toda vez que você mudar o `<option>` do `<select>`, você ativa o display da `<div>` referente à ele. Veja este código funcionando [aqui](http://codepen.io/caio1511/pen/KpMEJr).

Note que, se você decidir trocar a sua escolha, você vai mostrar o conteúdo referente e esconder qualquer outro que já estivesse sido mostrado. É isso que a linha `$(_seletor).siblings().removeClass('active');` faz.

Vale apontar que este é um jeito de resolver o seu problema, com base no seu HTML. Caso as `<div>` de conteúdo não sejam irmãs, esta técnica não funciona. Se, no DOM, houverem outros elementos irmãos que não as `div` de conteúdo, você pode ter problemas, por conta da atribuição das classes.

Existem outros jeitos de se obter o resultado, um deles, é usando o método [`toggleClass`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).